# How to create a reusable component in VueJs?

Tags: vuejs2, vue-component, vue-router, html-framework-7

I would like to create Side Panel as a reusable component in Framework7 with VueJS. Here is my code..

[image: project structure]

Card.vue

```
<f7-card>
  <f7-card-header>Card header content</f7-card-header>
  <f7-card-content><img src="https://wiki.videolan.org/images/Ubuntu-logo.png"></img></f7-card-content>
  <f7-card-footer>Card footer content</f7-card-footer>
</f7-card>
```

Now i registered as a component like below,

```
import Vue from 'vue'
export default [
    {
        path: '/card/',
        component: require('./Card')
    },
]
```

In later vues i imported as,

```
import Card from './Card.vue'
```

and i try to access in another vues like,

Now i'm getting an error like

> [Vue warn]: Unknown custom element:  - did you register the
>   component correctly? For recursive components, make sure to provide
>   the "name" option.

Can anyone help me where have i mistaken?

Thanks,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not really clear from your code exactly what you are doing, but the error you are getting happens when you try to use a component as a child of another component without registering it in the parent's `components` setting like this:

```
<script>
import Card from './Card.vue'

export default {
  data () {
    return {
       somedata: 'some value'
    }
  },
  components: {Card: Card}, // <- you're missing this
  // etc...

}
</script>
```

You can also register components globally. More here: https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#Local-Registration

Comment: Again it is saying that... Failed to mount component: template or render function not defined. 
(found in <Card>...
I even added components: {Card, Card};

Answer (score 1):

Are you showing us all of Card.vue? For a valid  single-file vue component, I would expect to see `<template>`, `<script>` and `<style>` elements. The render function will be generated from whatever you put in the `<template>` element.

Comment: Adding <template>, <script> and <style> solved my problem... Now it is working with only one component.. when i try to add one more component by giving comma it is not accepting "You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type.
|             }
|         },
|         components: {FSidebar,FSidebar},{CSidebar,CSidebar}"

Comment: `components` is one object, inside which you have 'name':object, 'name':object. try `components = {'FSidebar':FSidebar,'CSidebar':CSidebar}`

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that the component that you want to reuse is wrapped inside a `template` tag
As follows

```
<template>
    <div>
        <component data/>
    <div/>
<template/>
```

Then register it inside the parent
Like so

```
export default {
  name: "Card",
  components: {
    Card
  },
};
```